# How to disable particular cell in Wpf datagrid on Radiobutton checked event

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to disable particular cell from Datagrid in wpf on the Radio button checked event. I got the row index and column index of the cell which I need to disable.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: I Agree , that in some sense you didn't try to explain any thing , 
but seeing as you might be very new , i gave you the simplest answer possible.

Answer (score 0):

CS :

```
   public class InverseConverter : IValueConverter
   {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
           bool _val = (bool)value;
           return !_val;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool _val = (bool)value;
            return !_val;
        }
   }


   public MainWindow()
   {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;        
   }

   public List<object> Stuff
   {
        get { return new List<object> { 1, 2, 3 }; }
   }
```

XAML :

```
<Window>
  <Grid>
     <Grid.Resources>
        <local:InverseConverter x:Key="converter" />
     </Grid.Resources>

     <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Stuff}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter}, Converter={StaticResource converter}, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                                          
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

     </DataGrid>        
 </Grid>
```